# JSTL c:set var From Inner (Included Page)

Tags: jsp, jstl, tiles

I have a common included JSP where a variable is set. That variable has to be accessible to the outer page which includes the JSP, but it is not recognized.

**common.jsp**

```
<c:set var="layoutDef" value="component" scope="request" />
```

**main.jsp**

```
<jsp:include page="common.jsp" />
<!-- Now do something with this included var. -->
<tiles:insert definition=".${layoutDef}.layout">
```

This is not a Tiles issue, although I am using Tiles. The variable "layoutDef" is not getting expanded.

The error thrown is

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error -  Tag Insert : Can't get definition '..layout'
```

which means the variable never got defined.

I found examples of the opposite: declaring a variable in the outer page, and then including a sub-page that uses that variable. Is it possible to go the other way?

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.

Just change this line:

```
<tiles:insert definition=".${layoutDef}.layout">
```

to this:

```
<tiles:insert definition=".${requestScope.layoutDef}.layout">
```